# What does the term "imperial" represent in beer styles or names?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to understand what I can assume about an "Imperial Stout" relative to a "Stout," etc.

I know anecdotally that they are "heavier," but online sources seem to lack agreement on a specific meaning, with some suggesting that they're hoppier, others saying they're higher alcohol content, and some using vague terms like "full-bodied".

Does "imperial" have a real, agreed-upon meaning, or is it just a marketing/description modifier that everyone uses differently?

Comment: I can't believe I have the ignominious honor of asking the first dupe here.  In my (meager) defense, the dupe wasn't there when I stared the question.  <sigh>